# Access to DAO in model - Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, dao, spring-data-mongodb

It is possible to have an access to DAO in model. I described model for collection "item" in  MongoDB like this:

```java
@Component
@Document( collection = "item" )
public class Item
{

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    private Integer     authId;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("mongoItemDao")
    private AuthorDao dao; 

    public Author getAuthor()
    {
         dao.findById(this.authId);
    }

    /* Others setters and getters */
}
```

As you can see I'm referring from "item" collection to "author" collection (One-to-Many relationship) and I would need to get exact object when requesting it. I believe that Hibernate do something similiar in background.

In app-context.xml I have

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="eu.cloudscale.showcase.db.dao.mongo.impl" />
```

where are implementations of DAOs.

Answer (score 0):

Should just try to :

```
@Component
@Document( collection = "item" )
public class Item
{

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    private Integer     authId;

    @DBRef
    private Author author; 

    /* Others setters and getters */
}
```